# How do you cancel a closed vote that you just placed?

Tags: support, closing

I just close-voted something, but had a change of heart on my decision. How to revert that decision?

Comment: If this is something you would like to be able to do, you may wish to hop over to the main meta and add support to this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't. You have to live forever with your guilt.

Comment: (Fingers crossed wishing I'm not wrong again)

Comment: You're *mostly* right. :) Close votes can age away if other users don't agree and the question isn't closed. If the question *is* closed, you can cast a reopen vote, though it doesn't really cancel out the earlier close vote.

Comment: Mods can also close and re-open to "clear" votes, but that should be reserved for when there's 4 votes on something that is obviously a good question that got picked on for some reason, etc.

Comment: @MatthewRead Ideally that shouldn't be done at all. Clearing votes like that is a hack at best. Just let them age away naturally, or reopen the question after it gets closed.

Comment: @AnnaLear I can't agree.  Even if there was a good feature for marking a question like that for follow-up and you somehow knew you'd be available at the time, waiting for the extra close vote serves no purpose.

Comment: And clearing such votes prevents the original voters from re-casting their previous vote.

Comment: @RavenDreamer They can't recast their vote under any circumstances anyway.

Comment: @MatthewRead Well, ideally the question just won't be closed if there's no longer a reason for it to be closed or the original vote was a mistake. :P

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't want to hijack comments here for a philosophical argument, so let's just say that in my experience clearing close votes is a good way to appear like you're throwing your diamond around. Even if folks are wrong and the question ends up getting closed for the wrong reasons, reopening it after the fact (with a meta discussion if needed) comes off a lot better than forcing the close votes out.

Comment: Overriding 5 people is better than overriding 4?  A Meta discussion can be had either way.